# Solrcloud & data import handler

Tags: java, solr, apache-zookeeper, solr4, solrcloud

I am planning to upgrade Solr from single instance option to cloud option. Currently I have 5 cores and each one is configured with data import handler. I have deployed web application along with solr.war inside tomcat folder which will trigger full imports & delta-imports periodically according to my project needs.

Now, I am planning to create 2 shards for this application keeping half of my 5 cores data into each shard.I am not to understand how DIH will work in SolrCloud?

- Is it fine if I start full-indexing from both shards?
- Or I need to do full indexing from only one shard?

Architecture will look like below
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by dividing 5 cores data into two shards? Do u mean you are going to "route" data to either shard based on some condition?

Comment: Thats what i was thinking.But i dont know if it is possible to achieve. Can you please suggest if there is any altenative?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you create your solr cloud: using composite id or implicit routing. Using composite id routing will take care of spreading the documents across all available shards. You can initiate the import from any solr cloud node. In the end the cloud environment will contain the imported document indices spread across all shards.
If you use implicit routing you have control where to keep each document index.
You do not have to use the DIH. Alternatively you can write a small app that uses the solr client to populate the index, which gives you more control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dont have freedom to do go away from DIH. If i start DIH from one machine then i will have issues with HA.How to make sure I achieve HA even if I start DIH from one machine?

Comment: What does "HA" mean? High Availability? Are you saying that you would like to import data while you have traffic ? You need to provide more feedback.

Comment: Yes.You are right. HA -> High Availability. I want import to happen parallely along with querying.This is what i was doing in single instance.

Comment: Let me summarize: you would like to import data from a data source to solr cloud using DIH while traffic still flows to the source? Or to solr cloud? Am i getting this right ?

Comment: Yes! you are right.trafic flows to source & it has to flow to solr cloud by delta imports.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of googling and reading I finally decided to implement DIH as follows. Please let me know your comments if you feel there will be issues with this architecture.

[image]